# Integrate Mail Chimp To custom Sign up form (Marketing Pro Theme)

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, mailchimp, mailchimp-api-v3.0

On my wordpress theme I have a sign-up form that is connected through [the newsletter plugin.](https://www.thenewsletterplugin.com) The developer of this premium theme said that i could use the newsletter plugin for the subscribers that sign-up then to transfer them over to mailchimp manually.

This is a bit messy and not something much of us would like to do. The code for the sign-up form is in a plugin that holds all of the special content for the theme.

I have been trying to replace the code for the newsletter plugin and add the code in this [instruction](http://kb.mailchimp.com/lists/signup-forms/host-your-own-signup-forms) from mailchimp

Here's the code that links the sign-up form to the newsletter plugin:

```
                if(function_exists('newsletter_form')):
      $output .=  '<div class="row">';
      $output .=  '<div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-6 col-md-4 col-md-offset-6">';
      $output .=  '<form method="post" action="'.home_url('/').'?na=s" onsubmit="return newsletter_check(this)">';
      $output .=  '<div class="c-input-3-wrapper">';
      $output .=  '<input class="c-input type-3" type="text" name="nn" required="" placeholder="'.esc_html($name_placehodler).'">';
      $output .=  '<div class="c-input-3-icon"><span class="lnr lnr-user"></span></div>';
      $output .=  '</div>';
      $output .=  '<div class="c-input-3-wrapper">';
      $output .=  '<input class="c-input type-3" type="email" name="ne" required="" placeholder="'.esc_html($email_placeholder).'">';
      $output .=  '<div class="c-input-3-icon"><span class="lnr lnr-envelope"></span></div>';
      $output .=  '</div>';
      $output .=  '<input class="newsletter-submit c-btn type-1 size-4 full" type="submit" value="'.esc_html($btn_text).'">';
      $output .=  '</form>';
      $output .=  '</div>';
      $output .=  '</div>';
    endif;
```

Here's the whole code for the style i am using.

```
       case 'style2':
  $output  =  '<div '.$id.' class="swiper-container tt-swiper-shadow'.$class.'" data-autoplay="'.esc_attr($autoplay).'" data-loop="'.esc_attr($loop).'" data-speed="'.esc_attr($speed).'" data-center="0" data-slides-per-view="1" data-add-slides="2">';
  $output .=  '<div class="swiper-wrapper clearfix">';
  foreach ($rs_hero_slider as $key => $slide) {
    $active_class      = ($key === 0) ? ' active':'';
    $object_id         = (isset($slide['atts']['object'])) ? $slide['atts']['object']:'';
    $small_heading     = (isset($slide['atts']['small_heading'])) ? $slide['atts']['small_heading']:'';
    $big_heading       = (isset($slide['atts']['heading'])) ? $slide['atts']['heading']:'';
    $form_id           = (isset($slide['atts']['form_id'])) ? $slide['atts']['form_id']:'';
    $email_placeholder = (isset($slide['atts']['email_placehodler'])) ? $slide['atts']['email_placehodler']:'Your Email';
    $name_placehodler  = (isset($slide['atts']['name_placehodler'])) ? $slide['atts']['name_placehodler']:'Your Name';
    $btn_text          = (isset($slide['atts']['btn_text'])) ? $slide['atts']['btn_text']:'Gimmie Pro Tips';

    $output .=  '<div class="swiper-slide'.$active_class.'" data-val="'.esc_attr($key).'">';
    $output .=  '<div class="tt-mslide-2">';
    $output .=  '<div class="container">';
    $output .=  '<div class="tt-mslide-2-table">';
    $output .=  '<div class="tt-mslide-2-cell">';
    if(is_numeric($object_id) && !empty($object_id)) {
      $object_url = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $object_id, 'full' );
      if(isset($object_url[0])) {
        $output .=  '<img class="tt-mslide-2-img img-responsive" src="'.esc_url($object_url[0]).'" height="996" width="640" alt="">';
      }
    }
    $output .=  '<div class="row">';
    $output .=  '<div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-6">';
    $output .=  '<h1 class="tt-mslide-2-title c-h1"'.$big_heading_color.'>'.esc_html($big_heading).'</h1>';
    $output .=  '<div class="simple-text size-4">';
    $output .=  '<p'.$small_heading_color.'>'.esc_html($small_heading).'</p>';
    $output .=  '</div>';
    $output .=  '</div>';
    $output .=  '</div>';

    if(function_exists('newsletter_form')):
      $output .=  '<div class="row">';
      $output .=  '<div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-6 col-md-4 col-md-offset-6">';
      $output .=  '<form method="post" action="'.home_url('/').'?na=s" onsubmit="return newsletter_check(this)">';
      $output .=  '<div class="c-input-3-wrapper">';
      $output .=  '<input class="c-input type-3" type="text" name="nn" required="" placeholder="'.esc_html($name_placehodler).'">';
      $output .=  '<div class="c-input-3-icon"><span class="lnr lnr-user"></span></div>';
      $output .=  '</div>';
      $output .=  '<div class="c-input-3-wrapper">';
      $output .=  '<input class="c-input type-3" type="email" name="ne" required="" placeholder="'.esc_html($email_placeholder).'">';
      $output .=  '<div class="c-input-3-icon"><span class="lnr lnr-envelope"></span></div>';
      $output .=  '</div>';
      $output .=  '<input class="newsletter-submit c-btn type-1 size-4 full" type="submit" value="'.esc_html($btn_text).'">';
      $output .=  '</form>';
      $output .=  '</div>';
      $output .=  '</div>';
    endif;

    $output .=  '<div class="tt-mslide-2-arrow">';
    $output .=  '<span class="lnr lnr-chevron-down"></span>';
    $output .=  '</div>';                                    

    $output .=  '</div>';
    $output .=  '</div>';
    $output .=  '</div>';
    $output .=  '</div>';
    $output .=  '</div>';

  }

  $output .=  '</div>';
  $output .=  '<div class="pagination type-1 pos-1 visible-xs-block"></div>';
  $output .=  '<div class="swiper-arrow-left tt-arrow-left type-1 '.$pagination_class.' pos-1 hidden-xs"><span class="lnr lnr-chevron-left"></span></div>';
  $output .=  '<div class="swiper-arrow-right tt-arrow-right type-1 '.$pagination_class.' pos-1 hidden-xs"><span class="lnr lnr-chevron-right"></span></div>';                   
  $output .=  '</div>';

  break;

case 'style3':`enter code here`
}
```